# Excel VBA - Date and IF Function inside the VBA is giving an error

Tags: vba, excel

I have a requirement where in, I am trying to find if the date in the data is greater than or equal to the current date then it should say "YES".

This is my code,

```
RDate = Application.WorksheetFunction.if(RSDate>=Date, "YES", "NO")
```

My error is Object doesn't support property of this method. Kindly help me with this. Share your thoughts

Comment: You could use this `RDate = IIF(RSDate>=Date, "YES", "NO")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `DateDiff` function, you can learn how to use it here [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251417.aspx)

```
If DateDiff("d", Date, RSDate) >= 0 Then
    RDate = "YES"
Else
    RDate = "NO"
End If
```

Comment: @VBA_Begineer You're welcome, thanks for accepting as answer. Also other answers here work, I prefer to work with Excel's capabilities, and if working with `Date`s, why not use their dates functions ?

Comment: I've just found `DateDiff` will handle text dates or number so a better choice. Nice one @Shai

Answer (score 3):

there's no such function as `Application.WorksheetFunction.if()`

to stick to a one-liner you may want to use `IIf()` function:

```
RDate = IIf(RSDate >= Date, "YES", "NO")
```

Comment: Wow. Every day really is a school day. I've never seen `IIF` used in VBA.

Comment: @CLR, `IIf()` must be used keeping in mind that it doesn't _short-circuit_ so that both expressions will be evaluated. Therefore you _must be sure_ (like this is the case) that both expressions can't return an error, or the whole statement where `IIf()` is in will error out

Comment: Thanks. I did Google it and read the same warning. Good to know. How on earth have I been doing this 15 or so years and never once come across it I'll never know.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use `If` ?

```
If RSDate>=Date then 
    RDate = "YES"
Else
    RDate = "NO"
End If
```

Or `Case` - which would be useful if you need more than 2 RDate outputs?

```
Select Case RSDate
    Case Is >= Date
        RDate = "YES"
    Case Else
        RDate = "NO"
End Select
```

Comment: Thanks CLR. The first one that you gave doesn't work for some reason. But thanks again.

Comment: No problem, though I'm curious as to how it doesn't work as it's a direct translation of your original example. Maybe RSDate is a string? That would be a good cause to use @Shai's answer as `DateDiff` converts string to date before the comparison.

Comment: Yes I believe that's the only reason for that as well.